# Remove leading zeros with special character

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have a column `Device` in a SQL Server table:

| Device |
| --- |
| DC_003_08TX |
| DC_010_04TX |
| DC_100_10TX |
| DC_004_00TX |
| DC_120_119TX |

I'm trying to write a query that removes the first 3 characters (`DC_`), removes the last non integer characters, and also replaces `_` with `-`.

This query does just that:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE (SUBSTRING(Device, 4, LEN(Device) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', REVERSE(Device)) - 3 + 1), '_', '-') AS Device
```

Now, I need to modify this query to remove the leading zeros from the columns and if there are double zeros behind the `-`, remove the double zeros and the `-`.

For example, the table above should now look like below:

| DeviceNew |
| --- |
| 3-8 |
| 10-4 |
| 100-10 |
| 4 |
| 120-119 |

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What version of sql server are you using?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: What do you want to happen if there are edge case values, like one or zero underscores, four underscores, no numeric digits in the second or third position, etc.

Comment: ...or a prefix like `DC1_` or `D_`...

Comment: I'm running SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way on < 2022:

```
  WITH agg AS
  (
    SELECT Device, 
           a = NULLIF(MAX(a), 0), 
           b = NULLIF(MAX(b), 0)
    FROM
    (
      SELECT Device,
         a = CASE WHEN [key] = 1 THEN TRY_CONVERT(int, value) END,
         b = CASE WHEN [key] = 2 THEN TRY_CONVERT(int, 
             LEFT(value, LEN(value) - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', 
             REVERSE(value)) + 1)) END
      FROM dbo.[a SQL Server table] 
      CROSS APPLY 
      OPENJSON(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(Device, '_', '","'), '"]"')) AS j
      WHERE j.[key] IN (1,2)
    ) AS src
    GROUP BY Device
  )
  SELECT Device, 
    CONCAT(a, CASE WHEN a > 0 AND b > 0 THEN '-' END, b)
  FROM agg;
```

- [Example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LIN7pfe6)

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am just going to assume you are using SQL Server 2022. As such I am using `STRING_SPLIT` with the optional ordinal position. If you are on an older version of SQL Server you will need to use a different string splitter. Here is [one such example](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function).

Of course I would suggest that part of the issue you are facing is because you have broken 1NF by sticking multiple values inside a single tuple which you now have to break apart.

The only caveat to this is that in your example you only provided a single column and as such there is nothing we can use for an order by to ensure the rows are in the same order as your sample data. I will leave the ordering problem to you, there are many ways that can be solved.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Device varchar(30)
)

insert @Something values
('DC_003_08TX')
, ('DC_010_04TX')
, ('DC_100_10TX')
, ('DC_004_00TX')
, ('DC_120_119TX')

SELECT max(case when x.ordinal = 2 then try_convert(varchar(10), try_convert(int, x.value)) end) 
    + isnull('-' + nullif(try_convert(varchar(10), try_convert(int, max(case when x.ordinal = 3 then left(x.value, len(x.value) - 2) end))), 0), '')
from @Something s
cross apply string_split(s.Device, '_', 1) x
group by s.Device
```